# In angular ui-router is it possible to animate specific view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, animation, angular-ui-router

To animate state changes in angular.js ui-router there are classes for `enter` and on `leave`. It means that when I make an animation it will always the same for every view.

This example is not mine, but notice that when I go back to a previous state the animation is the same, it goes left. http://embed.plnkr.co/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC/preview

Is there a way to add animation per state or on other events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the animations are applied through CSS it seems your only option is to determine what CSS should be applied based on the new state and previous state. It is easy to apply a class to the outgoing view on view change events, but much more difficult for the incoming view.

This should work but involves hacking angular-ui-router.js. I think it should be relatively straight forward to write this functionality into an extension script of some kind.

- Create different CSS classes for the different animations that will be performed. E.g. slide-left and slide-right as shown below.
- In the forms controller add a scope variable that indicates which animation should take place e.g. `$scope.animationType`.
- In the forms controller add a listener to the view change event that will change the value of `$scope.animationType` depending on the current and future states. The value should match the CSS class with the animation you want to perform.
- In angular-ui-router.js find the `cleanupLastView` function and add the parameter and the first first two lines:

.

```
function cleanupLastView(clonedElement) {
        if(clonedElement) clonedElement.attr("class", scope.animationType);
        if(currentEl) currentEl.attr("class", scope.animationType);
...
```

Then you have to change the call to `cleanupLastView` so the cloned element is included: `cleanupLastView(clone)`

Abbreviated CSS with `@keyframes` not included.

```
.form-view-slide-left.ng-enter            {
    animation:slideInRight 0.5s both ease;
}
.form-view-slide-left.ng-leave            {
    animation:slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease;
}
.form-view-slide-right.ng-enter            {
    animation:slideInLeft 0.5s both ease;
}
.form-view-slide-right.ng-leave            {
    animation:slideOutRight 0.5s both ease;
}
```